# Required fields not working as form submits before validation

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I am trying to get the required fields working but the form submits before the validation is done and I am not sure how I can fix it. Is there anyway I can fix this?

Apologies in advance for the messy code.

```
<html>
   <script>
      function submitToAPI(e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url : URL,
                    dataType: "json",
                    crossDomain: "true",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),                 
   </script> 
   
<body>
      <form id="contact-form" method="POST">
      <div class="formcontainer">
      <div id='key'>
         <label for="requestoremail"><strong>Requestor's Email Address</strong></label>
         <input required class="defaultclass" id='requestoremail' type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address" name="requestoremail"  >
         <label for="purpose"><strong>Purpose of Request</strong></label>
         <input required class="defaultclass" id='purpose'type="text" placeholder="Enter purpose of the key " name="purpose" >
      </div>
      <div id='secret'>
         <label for="secretname"><strong>Secret Name</strong></label>
         <input class="secretclass" id='secretname' type="text" placeholder="Enter name of secret" name="secretname" >
         <label for="secretvalue"><strong>Secret Value </strong></label>
         <input class="secretvalueclass" id='secretvalue' type="text" placeholder="Enter value of secret" name="secretvalue" >
      </div>
      <button form="contact-form" type="button" onClick="submitToAPI(event)" class="btn btn-lg" >Submit</button>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".defaultclass").attr('required',true);
                $(".secretclass").attr('required',false);
                $("#secret").hide();
                $("#key").show();
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can try overriding the submit function by using event.preventDefault, then run your checks and submit manually.

Comment: There's no closing `</form>` tag. Also a `<button>` with `type="button"` doesn't submit a form and won't therefor trigger the validation routine of the form.

Comment: And don't use inline events, like that `onClick`, and rely on that [deprecated global `event` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) when you have jQuery (or even without) available.

Answer (score 0):

Your button has no knowledge of the form it resides inside. You only get automatic validation when the button's type is `submit`.  Because it is of type `button`, it is just that, a button.

However, you can programatically check if your form is valid before firing your ajax call

```
// true if your form passes the validity check
const isValid = document.getElementById('contact-form').checkValidity();
```

Comment: Do I add the ajax into an IF ELSE statement? Somehow it is not working for me